# How to apply separate styling to tables in Python ReportLab lib?

Tags: python, python-3.6, reportlab

As per the documentation of opensource "Report Lab" lib, it says table styles are overridden from previous table to current table. Is there any way to control this behaviour? Or one has to go with license version only?
I would have posted code snippets its a general query.